# How to replace the payload from json object in mule

Tags: regex, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

Prepared json request like below.

```
[{
    "type": "John",
    "attributes": {
        "AA": [{
            "value": "1234"
        }]
    }
}, 
{

}
]
```

I need to replace the below one with empty i.e means blank ''.

```
, 
    {

    }
```

Could you please provide the solution for this.

Finally It should come like below.

```
[{
        "type": "John",
        "attributes": {
            "AA": [{
                "value": "1234"
            }]
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches the given sequence however you would probably need to change it to accept all possibilities:

```
/, \n\{\W+?\}/
```

Just replace the match with nothing.

Comment: It is giving Illegal escape sequence.could you please provide exact one :)

Comment: tried having payload.replace with above expression. Did not work. Could you please someone will provide solution how to do it in mule :)

Comment: @Gopi remember that SO is not a free coding platform. Have you ever written a regex? You need to try things yourself, this is just a generic regex, it needs proper escaping to work in whatever environment you have.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the response as a JSON object or as a string?

If you get the response as an object you have to stringify it before applying the replace function:

```
payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload).replace(/,\{\}/, ''))
```

If the response you posted above is already stringified and you haven´t parsed it into an object, the method is:

```
payload = payload.replace(/\,\s+\n\s+\{\n\s+\}/,'')
```

Comment: preparing the request as json and sending it over http call before sending it to http. we need to remove the whereever we have , { } and send the request.

Comment: Then just do the first option:

    payload = [{
        "type": "John",
        "attributes": {
            "AA": [{
                "value": "1234"
                }]
            }
        }, 
        {

        }
    ];
    payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload).replace(/,\{\}/, '')) 
where payload is your object

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this purpose, we can use DataWeave expression whether in *Transform Message* or in MEL.

In this case I prefer to use it in MEL: `#[dw('payload filter (sizeOf $) > 0')]`

Comment: Hi Sulthony- I have same use case as questioner. Where exactly do you use this MEL? Payload need to be json or object?  Thanks!

Comment: I will use that MEL inside the **Set Payload** transformer, and the payload can be both: json or object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flatten` operator here as given below. It should remove empty `json`. Also you can try replace `{}` with `null` and adding `skipnullon="everywhere"`

```
flatten payload
```